# MySQL CASE with user parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: sql, mysql, grafana

I am trying to obtain all days to a month in my MySQL database.
This query is being called in one of my Grafana dashboards that has a variable for the year, the month and the day. This query is supposed to get all the days there are to the selected month. The user can select a written month, but the months in my table are numbers. Since Grafana doesn't seem to allow you to value map the variables, I'll have to do that in my SQL query. Sadly the query doesn't seem to work and only returns this error:
`[42S22][1054] Unknown column 'January' in 'where clause'`
Of course the month depends on what the user has chosen.
This is my SQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(measurement_timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM measurement_timestamp) = ${Year}
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM measurement_timestamp) = CASE
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'January' THEN 1
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'February' THEN 2
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'March' THEN 3
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'April' THEN 4
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'May' THEN 5
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'June' THEN 6
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'July' THEN 7
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'August' THEN 8
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'September' THEN 9
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'October' THEN 10
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'November' THEN 11
                            WHEN ${Month} = 'December' THEN 12
    END
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: What is going on with the JavaScript-style `${Month}` interpolation?

Comment: As I said, this is the form Grafana handles variables, as this is a query used in a Grafana dashboard. But other programs can handle them as well. Just not MySQL as it seems...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Grafana client seems to be doing interpolation, not parameters.

There's a difference between interpolating a value into an SQL query *before* it is parsed, and sending a parameter to a prepared query *after* it is parsed.

The difference is important when the value you are sending is a string.

```
...
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM measurement_timestamp) = 2023
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM measurement_timestamp) = 
  CASE
   WHEN March = 'January' THEN 1
...
```

You can see that if we use interpolation, it's okay to interpolate an integer value like `2023`. There's no syntax problem.

But if we interpolate a string value like `March`, it ends up looking like a column name or SQL keyword, because it's not inside single-quotes, as string literals must be.

This would work:

```
...
  CASE
   WHEN 'March' = 'January' THEN 1
...
```

A true SQL parameter would send the value *after* the query is parsed by the server as a prepared SQL statement. In that case, you don't have to use the single-quotes, because a parameter is always treated as a scalar value, regardless of whether it's a string or an integer. It won't be ambiguous to the SQL parser, because the value isn't seen by the parser. It's combined with the prepared SQL statement during execution.

I'm not sure if Grafana can do true SQL parameterized statements. That's something for you to investigate in the Grafana documentation, if you want.

In the meantime, you could solve this problem with interpolation simply by putting the variable inside single-quotes:

```
...
  CASE
   WHEN '${Month}' = 'January' THEN 1
...
```

Be warned that this is in fact a potential SQL injection vulnerability. If you can't ensure that `$Month` is *always* a safe string, one of the 12 month names and never anything else, then it's not a secure way of running queries.

By the way, you commented that you don't like the repetitive expression. You should know that `CASE` expressions can be written with another syntax like this:

```
...
  CASE '${Month}'
   WHEN 'January' THEN 1
   WHEN 'February' THEN 2
...
```

So you only need to write the variable once, and the `WHEN` clauses only have the value to compare to (this works only if you would compare with `=`, and the left side of the comparison is the same for every case). This is standard syntax in every implementation of SQL.

Comment: Thanks to you all for the helpful replies. This one ended up working for me. Thanks to all the others as well.

Answer (score 2):

mysql supports [monthname](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_monthname)

So your query would look more like

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(measurement_timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM measurement_timestamp) = ${Year}
  AND MONTHNAME( measurement_timestamp) = ${Month} 
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

If you need the number you need to enclose the ${month} in single quotes, so that MySQL interprets the monthname as string and not as column name

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(measurement_timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM my_table
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM measurement_timestamp) = ${Year}
  AND EXTRACT(MONTH FROM measurement_timestamp) = CASE
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'January' THEN 1
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'February' THEN 2
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'March' THEN 3
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'April' THEN 4
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'May' THEN 5
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'June' THEN 6
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'July' THEN 7
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'August' THEN 8
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'September' THEN 9
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'October' THEN 10
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'November' THEN 11
                WHEN '${Month}' = 'December' THEN 12
    END
ORDER BY timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: This is very helpful, but doesn't seem to fix my problem. It still returns the same error.
I think it's the wrong way around. As I understand the function would return the month name to a date, but the user is entering the month name and I need to convert it to the number of the month.

Comment: i added a solution  to your problem, but still you should use my solution it is faster

Answer (score 0):

I'd be inclined to approach this slightly differently, especially if you have an index on `measurement_timestamp`. If you convert your `{Year}` and `{Month}` variables to a date, you can then use a date range in your `WHERE` which would be sargable. Converting your month and year to a date can be done with `STR_TO_DATE` AND `DATE_FORMAT`, so the below would create a date variable of `2024-03-01` from separate month and year inputs:

```
SET @Month ='March';
SET @Year = '2024';
SET @Date = DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ','01', @Month, @Year), '%d %M %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d');
```

You can then put this in your query, e.g.

```
WHERE measurement_timestamp >= @Date
AND measurement_timestamp < @Date + INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

If you want to avoid variables and also avoid repeating your conversion, you could put this in a derived query, ending up with something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(t.measurement_timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM my_table AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT_WS(' ','01', '{Month}', '{Year}'), '%d %M %Y'),'%Y-%m-%d') AS DateStart) AS d
WHERE t.measurement_timestamp >= d.DateStart
AND t.measurement_timestamp< d.DateStart +INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

[Simplified example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/l37djIBm)

Alternatively you can do the same thing (i.e. convert the incoming parameters to a date rather than functions on the date column) with `MAKEDATE()`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT DAY(t.measurement_timestamp) AS timestamp
FROM my_table AS t
CROSS JOIN (SELECT MAKEDATE({Year}, 1)
                + INTERVAL 
                CASE
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'January' THEN 0
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'February' THEN 1
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'March' THEN 2
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'April' THEN 3
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'May' THEN 4
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'June' THEN 5
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'July' THEN 6
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'August' THEN 7
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'September' THEN 8
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'October' THEN 9
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'November' THEN 10
                    WHEN '${Month}' = 'December' THEN 11
                END MONTH AS DateStart) AS d
WHERE t.measurement_timestamp >= d.DateStart
AND t.measurement_timestamp< d.DateStart +INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

[Further example on db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YvWON_1H)

Comment: `MAKEDATE(@Year, 1) + INTERVAL 2 MONTH` seems like a simpler ane more efficient solution than `STR_TO_DATE`

Comment: @Charlieface I'm not that familiar with MySQL so I can't work out how to incorporate the `{Month}` variable into that without the same case expression which I personally found unbecoming. Readability is subjective though, so I have updated the answer with this solution too. I stand by the premise though, convert the parameters and use a date range filter and not perform conversions on the data.

Answer (score 0):

Premise of your question is wrong. Specifically this part:

> Since Grafana doesn't seem to allow you to value map the variables, I'll have to do that in my SQL query

Grafana in fact allows creation of variables with labels and values that differ.
For example, Custom variable can be defined with the following *Value*:

```
label1 : value1, label2 : value2
```

This way you will see in dropdown labels "label1", "label2".

And you can use this variable in the following way:

- `$var` or `${var:value}` will return value of selected item, for example `value1`,
- `${var:text}` will return label of selected item, for example `lable1`.

You can see demo [here](https://play.grafana.org/d/c9ouF7LMk/key-value-variable-in-title?orgId=1).

And for the case described in the question you'll need *Value* field of variable to be set to

```
January : 1, February : 2, March : 3, ...
```

Similarly this can be done in Query variables, with use of either named regex groups or columns with names `__text` and `__value`, if your data source allows columns.

Comment: Since I'm using a query and not a custom variable type, I don't see how this would work in my case. Still appreciate the answer and I'm sure I might use it another time.

Comment: @Wyatt, it depend really on what you query is. But as I mentioned in the answer it's possible: you simply need to return columns `__text` and `__value`. Something like `select 'January' as __text, 1 as __value union all select 'Februaury', 2 union all ...`

Comment: I figured out what you meant. This was also really helpful. Thanks. This actually fixed another problem for me that I had.